# ASP.NET MVC 2 DataAnnotation based Validation conflict with LINQ2SQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

ASP.NET MVC 2, gives a good functionality of annotation based validation, but to use this functionality I need to reference two files (Microsoft.Web.Mvc.ModelBinders.dll and  **System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll**) as described [here](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/04/dataannotations-and-aspnet-mvc.html)

I use LINQ2SQL, to create my entities. And it uses it's own annotations within Entity classes, which needs another version of **System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll**

So currently I'm able to use one of them (either validation or linq2sql)
Does anyone encountered same problem? Or does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is create MetaData classes for the fields that you want to valdiate,

http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-39-cs.aspx (Using Data Annotation Validators with the Entity Framework)